# Problem with ESS when running R: .load.ESSR and .ess.eval errors

Tags: ess

I have installed ESS on emacs v27.1. When I enter M-x R , R launches but I get the error message:

load ESSR: Error in load.ESSR("~/.emacs.d/elpa/ess-20230404.912/etc/ESSR/R"): could not find function load.ESSR
The message disappears after a few seconds.

Another problem (which may be related.)

Script file: test.r

square <- function(x) return(x*x)

When I type C-c C-c, I get the error message,
Error in .ess.eval("square <- function(x)\n{ return(x * x)\n}", visibly = TRUE,  : could not find function ".ess.eval"
Thank you

Comment: I have figured it out: I forgot to add the line (add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/elpa/ess/lisp") in the .emacs file. Thank you for reading this.